# Curved pyramid cross section equation (image included)

Tags: geometry

Pyramids (cones, tetrahedrons etc.) and hemispheres are similar in the way the start from a bigger base and close to a point at the top.

I think the equation for the cross sectional area of a pyramid given its maximum height ($height$) and a specific height ($y$) is:

$$(1 - \frac{y}{\text{height}}) \times \text{baseArea}$$

And for an hemisphere is:

$$\pi \times (height^2 - y^2)$$

Intuitively I feel like there are intermediate 3d geometric shapes that exist between and hemisphere and a pyramid, by curving each edge of the vertical faces by a certain amount for example.

Is there any equation that lets me obtain the cross area of any shape given these qualities? What are the other shapes I mentioned? How do I calculate the csa for them or define them?

**Edit**

I still didn't get the equation I'm looking for but I generated somewhat of a model in 3D with matplotlib.

In this case is a square pyramid with edges curved by averaging (geometric average) with the circumferences of an hemisphere of same radius as the pyramid's height with center in the center of the base of the pyramid.
[image: curved pyramid]